# Shell Scripting for find and replace with confirmation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, vi

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 in making scripts.In my bash file i have a code here:

```
sed -i 's/error/right/g'  hello.txt
```

This is for the global find and replace in my file "hello.txt". 
**How can I convert it to make it a find and replace script with confirmation?**

Comment: Is this a homework question? =}

Comment: You must write your own code to improve your coding skill, I just leave a suggestion. Use `read` commadn to ask confirmation [link](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php) and replace code `sed -i "s/OLD_TEXT_NEED_TO_REPLACE/NEW_TEXT_FOR_REPACE/g" FILE_PATH`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can invoke vi editor with search and replace command with confirmation:

```
$ vi -c '1,$ s/error/right/c' hello.txt
```

or from within vim

```
:s/error/right/gc
```

Comment: yes i tried it. It work by the way. But my problem is i should make it as a script. So it means it should be in a bash file.